# How to make a hard-coded HTTP processing script dynamic?

Tags: python, http, jython, maximo, oslc

I have a Jython 2.7 script that receives a URL and uses the parameters/values in the URL to create or update records.

- Example URL: `http://server:host/maximo/oslc/script/CREATEWO?&wonum=WO0001&description=Legacy&classstructureid=1666&wopriority=1&worktype=CM`

---

Details:

1. Receive the URL and put the parameters/values in variables:

> ```
> from psdi.server import MXServer
> from psdi.mbo import MboSet
>
> resp = {}
> wonum =             request.getQueryParam("wonum")
> description =       request.getQueryParam("description")
> classstructureid =  request.getQueryParam("classstructureid")
> wopriority =        request.getQueryParam("wopriority")
> worktype =          request.getQueryParam("worktype")
> ```

2. Some lines that aren't relevant to the question:

> ```
> woset = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet("workorder",request.getUserInfo())
> whereClause = "wonum= '" + wonum + "'"
>
> woset.setWhere(whereClause)
> woset.reset()
> woMbo = woset.moveFirst()
> ```

3. Then use the values to either create a new record or update an existing record:

> ```
> #If workorder already exists, update it:
> if woMbo is not None:
>   woMbo.setValue("description", description)
>   woMbo.setValue("classstructureid", classstructureid)
>   woMbo.setValue("wopriority", wopriority)
>   woMbo.setValue("worktype", worktype)
>   woset.save()
>   woset.clear()
>   woset.close()
>   resp[0]='Updated workorder ' + wonum
> #Else, create a new workorder
> else:
>   woMbo=woset.add()
>   woMbo.setValue("wonum",wonum)
>   woMbo.setValue("description", description)
>   woMbo.setValue("classstructureid", classstructureid)
>   woMbo.setValue("wopriority", wopriority)
>   woMbo.setValue("worktype", worktype)
>   woset.save()
>   woset.clear()
>   woset.close()
>   resp[0]='Created workorder ' + wonum
> responseBody =resp[0]
> ```

---

Question:

Unfortunately, the field names/values are **hardcoded in 3 different places** in the script.

I would like to enhance the script so that it is dynamic -- not hardcoded.

- In other words, it would be great if the script could accept a list of parameters/values and simply loop through them to update or create a record in the respective fields.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are working always with the same query parameters, rather than define variables, loop through a list of strings and put them as key-value pairs

To populate

```
items = ["wonum", "description"]
resp = {k: request.getQueryParam(k) for k in items}
```

Then to set

```
for i in items:
    woMbo.setValue(i, resp[i])
```

---

Otherwise, you are looking for [`URL parsing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html) and the `getQuery` method, followed by a `split("=")`, giving you `["wonum", "WO0001", "description", "Legacy"]`, for example, and you can loop over every other element to get you dynamic entries

```
l = ["wonum", "WO0001", "description", "Legacy"]
for i in range(0, len(l)-1, 2):
    print(f'key:{l[i]}\tvalue:{l[i+1]}')
```

```
key:wonum   value:WO0001
key:description value:Legacy
```

---

Note: This is subject to SQL injection attacks, and should be fixed

```
whereClause = "wonum= '" + wonum + "'"
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using the Maximo Next Gen. REST API to execute an automation script that accepts an HTTP request with parameters and creates or updates a Work Order in the system.  You want to make your script more generic (presumably to accept more paramaters for the created/updated work order) and/or other mbo's.

This can be achieved without developing automation scripts and just using the Next Gen. API you're already using to execute the script.  The API already accepts create & update requests on the mxwo object structure with the ability to use all the fields, child objects, etc.

https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/restguide/Maximo_Nextgen_REST_API.html#_creating_and_updating_resources